# FPTAS for approximating the permanent of a matrix

Tags: computational-complexity, matrix-analysis, approximation-algorithms, permanent

My question concerns approximating permanent of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix.

Several approximation algorithms have been proposed in the literature for this purpose, whose time complexity depend on $n$ and accuracy $\epsilon$ (e.g., in the following paper by Linial et al.: "*A deterministic strongly polynomial algorithm for matrix scaling and approximate permanents.*")

In order to get an FPTAS, we have to choose $\epsilon$ as a function of $n$. For examples it is mentioned in Linial's paper that for the purpose of approximating the permanent, it 
suffices to choose $\epsilon=n^{-2}$ (last paragraphs of Section 1 of the above paper).

Anyone could give me some hints why this choice of $\epsilon$ is sufficient?

Comment: Because you can pad the input matrix with diagonal entries to dimension, say, $m=n/\epsilon$ while preserving the permanent, and then $m^{-2}<\epsilon$.